# Can I use a Crikit Broadband 3G moden through virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, modem

okay bear with me if this if this is a dumb question but I have just got Virtual box  on my ubuntu system.  I may be loosing connection at home soon and am thinking of getting a crikit broadband 3g modem just to have the net, even if it is slow.  What I need to know is can I use XP on VB to set it up and then have it work through linux since it doesn't support linux, Use it only on vbox through ubuntu or would it even work?

Answer (score 1):

I have the cricket a600 what i had to do was install the usb_modeswitch.But first install and set up on a windows machine just so that your card will be activated,then plug it in,you see up in your network manager a something called "new mobile device" or some thing smiler. click on it and just fallow the steps,and give it a password,or mark it for all users,and auto connect if you want it to do so.

Comment: cool  I imagine that they use windows at the dealer so they can set it up when I buy it.  That fixes that issue and then plug and follow sounds easy enough.  Is it slow?  not complaining because slow net is better than no net just wondering about speed.

Comment: well i have used 2 air cards with ubuntu so far,,cricket and virgin mobile,I was getting about 1.5 down avg 2.1+ on a good day,,I dont know if i can say this hear but when i switched to virgin mobile i was a lot happier.If you go over 5gb of data with cricket,your speed gets slowed down for 30days,but with virgin if you go over you get slowed down to,but when you pay your next bill your speed comes back,with cricket the 30 day penaltie carry's over....

Answer (score 0):

Lots of 3G Broadband modems are supported in Linux even though the modem's box doesn't say so. While I've not used the specific modem that you are having, I've used two different Broadband modems with my Ubuntu. (Huwaei E1752 and another Huawei E150)

Both okay in Ubuntu. Just plug it in, then go to System > Preferences > Network Connections, Click on the Mobile Broadband tab and then click 'Add'. In the next few screens you will be asked to enter your Mobile Operator, Country, etc. and if everything goes well your Modem will be automatically connected to the Internet.